# Selenium send keys causing click function to break

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver, pyautogui

I'm working on building a booking bot for booking study rooms at school using Python, Selenium and Geckodriver. One step of booking a room is to search for the room you want, then click on that room. When you click on the room you get a drop down list where you see what times you can book for each day (see pics below)

[image: Closed drop down]

[image: Open drop down]

When I use the click function to choose my room, it will double click it which will close the drop down list and in turn break the rest of the code. The following is my code so far (be nice)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey
import time

def function(user, password, room, startTime, endTime, date):
    #Troubleshooting
    print(user, password, room, startTime, endTime)
    #Get first website
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get("https://se.timeedit.net/web/liu/db1/wr_stud/")

    #Locate and click link to login
    logInLink = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='logincontrol']/a[1]").click()
    #Enter credentials and log in
    usernameField = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='userNameInput']").send_keys(user)
    passwordField = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='passwordInput']").send_keys(password)
    logInButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='submitButton']").click()

    #Enter booking page. Sleep to let the page load, search for room and wait for the room to show
    bookingPageLink = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='utext']").click()
    roomField = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='objectinputtext']").send_keys(room)
    time.sleep(2)

    #Select room, wait for dropdown to finish, choose date and enter time
    roomButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='"+room+"']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    dateButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-dates='"+date+"']/div[@data-dates='"+date+"']").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    startTimeButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='first']/select[1]").click()

    #Finish code!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = open("infoLiu.txt", 'r')
    info = file.readlines()
    file.close
    function(info[0].rstrip('\n'), info[1].rstrip('\n'), info[2].rstrip('\n'), info[3].rstrip('\n'), info[4].rstrip('\n'), info[5].rstrip('\n'))`
```

Something weird i noticed when troubleshooting this is if instead use the typewrite() function from pyautogui to "type" in what room i want, like this.

```
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='objectinputtext']").click()
    typewrite(room)
    time.sleep(2)

    #Select room, wait for dropdown to finish, choose date and enter time
    roomButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='"+room+"']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    dateButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-dates='"+date+"']/div[@data-dates='"+date+"']").click()
    time.sleep(1)
    startTimeButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@class='first']/select[1]").click()
    #Finish code!
```

It will work and not a hint of double clicking the room.

EDIT: Just tried adding another click rigth after the click that causes problems, like this (sleep(2) and sleep(4) is just for easier troubleshooting):

```
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='objectinputtext']").send_keys(room)
    time.sleep(2)

    #Select room, wait for dropdown to finish, choose date and enter time
    roomButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='"+room+"']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    roomButton2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='"+room+"']").click()
    time.sleep(4)
    dateButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-dates='"+date+"']/div[@data-dates='"+date+"']").click()
```

The second click will execute like normal

*Any help is appreciated !!*